# React with Typescript giving error of - Cannot destructure property 'colored' of 'boxShadows' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

I downloaded the material dashboard react theme from the open source GitHub project and while converting the project into Typescript (React + Typescript), it's giving the following error (Attached Image)

[image]

I'm using the following configuration in my package.json

"@types/react": "^18.2.8",
"@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
"typescript": "^4.9.5",
"@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
"@mui/material": "^5.13.3",

Appreciate help!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without showing any code, but somewhere you must be doing something like:

```
const {colored} = boxShadows;
```

which fails when `boxShadows` is `undefined`. That's what the error means.

If you identified the place you are doing this, you could change it to use optional chaining:

```
const colored = boxShadows?.colored;
```